# Настройка плагина PHP и композер Yandex SpeechKit

Tags: php, apache, composer, yandex-speechkit

Нужна консультация по настройке `composer'a` и "разворачиванию" с помощью его плагина(если это можно так назвать).
Что хочу сделать? Отправить файл из примера и получить результат от `Yandex SpeechKit`

[SpeechKit](https://github.com/ZloeSabo/speechkit-php)
скачал.

Сделал вроде все по инструкции, файл `autoload.php` есть.

[Мой результат](https://github.com/Igor-Men/test-yandex-kit) запускаем index1.php

```
igor@igor-H81M-S2V:/var/www/shop2.localhost$ php -f index1.php 
PHP Fatal error: Class 'SpeechKit\SpeechContent\RawDataSpeech' not found in /var/www/shop2.localhost/lib/SpeechKit/SpeechContent/SpeechFactory.php on line 16

public static function fromData($data)
{
    if(is_file($data)) {
    return new File($data);
} else {
    return new RawDataSpeech($data); // проблема в то м что не находит класса
    }
}
```

Как сказано в ошибке: не находит класс, поискал - действительно его нет. Может как-то криво развернул? Или что-то нужно дописать в json настройку `composer'a` чтобы он загрузился? Кто имел опыт настройки composera, подскажите пожалуйста.
Спасибо.

Comment: Это не PSR-0 (а PSR-4), зря вы его туда запихнули. Да и неймспейсу SpeechKit соответствует lib/SpeechKit, а не просто lib. Если до завтра не разберетесь, смогу прогнать на локалке.

Comment: Пока разбераюсь, буду очень благодарен

Comment: Написал разрабочику в issues он ответил что еще небыл реализован недостающий класс(вернее не был залит на github). Он его залил и все заработало.